# Vref on a 12-bit DAC

Tags: circuit-design

I am using this MCP4922 12-bit DAC, and the range of voltage to convert is from 0-5 volts, what is the recommended voltage on its external Vref pin?!

Thanks

Comment: It is not like a power supply voltage where there is min/max/recommended.

Comment: There is no "recommended voltage" for Vref, you can freely choose it between 0 - 5 V depending on your application. So it depends on how you want to use the DAC what the Vref voltage should be. Suppose I answered: "The recommended Vref voltage is 3.1415 V", would you ask **why?**.

Comment: Since every answer except mine is being upvoted but no other answer will work, I guess I think the question is unclear! To me it is obvious that you want your output signal to be in the range of 0 to 5 volts. Is that correct? Otherwise I don't understand the "0-5 volts" part.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you are going to do with the output of your DAC.

The voltage you give Vref will be the maximum output of your DAC. If you give your DAC a decimal value of 4095 (largest 12 bit value), it will output Vref.

So Vout = Vref x (12 bit value / 4095).

Comment: But the input is 0-5 volts, are you suggesting an extra divider or buffer hardware?

Comment: @pipe I don't understand what you mean in relation to my response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this means if the maximum value for the conversion is 5-volt Vref must be 5Volt too.

Comment: If you want 5v to come out of the DAC when you send decimal 4095 (binary 1111 1111 1111), then you should give Vref 5v.

Answer (score 2):

If you pick 4.096V as suggested by others, you can use a reference that is regulated from a 5V supply. For example, [REF4132A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ref4132.pdf?ts=1604369251624&ref_url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FREF4132), but there are others.

If your input voltage is ratiometric to the supply then you might want to choose the supply voltage (with some care). Otherwise, typically the supply rail is a poor choice as a reference, especially for a relatively high resolution ADC.

Dividing the input voltage down a bit is less sensitive to resistor tolerances than a larger division and can allow slight overvoltage without danger to the ADC input. For example, with a 5V supply, 5.3V is allowable. With a 5:4.096 division you can apply almost 6.5V without exceeding the maximum. A divider made from inexpensive 0.1% tolerance resistors will only affect the output voltage  by about 0.036% or about 1.5 LSB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think in my current project I will use Vref to be the same as Vin (5 Volts) since it supplied by good buck-regulator

Comment: Usually that results in a lot of noise and a ‘reference’ that changes excessively with warm-up and ambient temperature, but maybe your (unstated) requirements are not very stringent. A lightly loaded linear regulator can be okay-ish.

Answer (score -1):

I see no reason using anything else than 5.0 volt. The relevant graphs in the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22250A.pdf) are figure 2-5 and 2-8, showing that while you have a lower (better) *DNL* for 5 volt vs something lower, you will have a *slightly* higher (worse) INL.

I haven't done the calculations but it seems reasonable that this slight difference will be less than the inaccuracies added if you try to use the internal Vref gain or use an external amplifier to change the input signal range.

Comment: You might just want the convenience of a 1 mV per count conversion and choose 4.095 V, for example.

Comment: @ThePhoton Maybe 30 years ago, not sure you should bother adding extra hardware just to get that these days.

Comment: What extra hardware? 4.095 V reference ICs are common.

Comment: @ThePhoton But OP writes in the question that they want a 0-5 volt signal, how do you get that with a 4.095 V reference without extra hardware?

Comment: If that's what they really want, then I agree. But then why even ask the question? If you know what maximum output voltage you want, then you just use that as the reference voltage and you're done.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer @pipe I guess I will use 5 Volts Vref.

Comment: @ThePhoton I didn't know that there is even a reference ICs and don't even know what Vref does with output signal levels, so I got a lot from this question.